# I mistakenly gave bounty to another answer

Tags: support

[In here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353076/how-to-indent-an-heredoc-inside-an-heredoc-the-right-way) I mistakenly gave bounty to another answer. The bounty should go to xhienne. I clicked on the blue box when it was seemingly clickable (about 10 seconds) but I couldn't undo my action. I ask the mods to please give the bounty to xhienne or allow me to undo my action in some way.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, this action is permanent. Moderators can refund a bounty before it is awarded, but once it's awarded, it stays awarded.

[From the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/270345):

> #### After awarding the bounty, can I remove it or move it to another answer at a later time?
>
> No, awarding is permanent. (But you're warned about that when actually
>   awarding the bounty.)